# Removing all of a certain value from an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been given the code below for ArrayList and have to write a new method in this class that will remove all of a given value from the ArrayList. I have been trying to write this function but for some reason cannot figure out how to access the list. I had to do the same thing for an LLList so I called the head node but I do not understand how to access the Array.

```
/*
 * ArrayList.java
 *
 */

import java.util.*;

/*
 * A class that implements our simple List interface using an array.
*/
public class ArrayList implements List {
private Object[] items;     // the items in the list
private int length;         // # of items in the list

/*
 * Constructs an ArrayList object with the specified maximum size
 * for a list that is initially empty.
 */
public ArrayList(int maxSize) {
    items = new Object[maxSize];
    length = 0;
}

/*
 * Constructs an ArrayList object containing the items in the specified
 * array, and with a max size that is twice the size of that array 
 * (to allow room for growth).
 */
public ArrayList(Object[] initItems) {
    items = new Object[2 * initItems.length];        
    for (int i = 0; i < initItems.length; i++) {
        items[i] = initItems[i];
    }

    length = initItems.length;
}

/*
 * length - returns the number of items in the list 
 */
public int length() {
    return length;
}

/* 
 * isFull - returns true if the list is full, and false otherwise
 */
public boolean isFull() {
    return (length == items.length);
}

/* getItem - returns the item at position i in the list */
public Object getItem(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    return items[i];
}

/* 
 * addItem - adds the specified item at position i in the list,
 * shifting the items that are currently in positions i, i+1, i+2,
 * etc. to the right by one.  Returns false if the list is full,
 * and true otherwise.
 */
public boolean addItem(Object item, int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else if (isFull()) {
        return false;
    }

    // make room for the new item
    for (int j = length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
        items[j + 1] = items[j];
    }

    items[i] = item;
    length++;
    return true;
}

/* 
 * removeItem - removes the item at position i in the list,
 * shifting the items that are currently in positions i+1, i+2,
 * etc. to the left by one.  Returns a reference to the removed
 * object.
 */
public Object removeItem(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    Object removed = items[i];

    // fill in the "hole" left by the removed item
    for (int j = i; j < length - 1; j++) {
        items[j] = items[j + 1];
    }
    items[length - 1] = null;

    length--;
    return removed;
}

/*
 * toString - converts the list into a String of the form 
 * {item0, item1, ...}
 */
public String toString() {
    String str = "{";

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str = str + items[i];
        if (i < length - 1) {
            str = str + ", ";
        }
    }

    str = str + "}";
    return str;
}

/*
 * iterator - returns an iterator for this list
 */
public ListIterator iterator() {
    // still needs to be implemented
    return null;
}
```

Comment: *"I do not understand how to access the Array"* it's right there `private Object[] items; // the items in the list`

Comment: When i try to do items.remove it tells me that it is of variable type jaba.lang.object and won't compile

Comment: listen to your error messages `items` is an array, it does not have a method `remove`

Comment: so then how would i remove an element?

Comment: you already have a `removeItem` function written for you in your custom `ArrayList` class.

Comment: It sounds like you need to clarify your understanding of what methods a native array has (e.g. `Object[]`) and what methods an abstracted class has (e.g. your `ArrayList` class).  I think you might be mixing the two up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you out a little more, here is a naive solution (it could be more efficient) that makes use of the given `removeItem` function. Just read it and try to understand it otherwise you'll have trouble down the line, if you have a question about it then feel free to ask.

```
public void removeAll(Object o) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (o.equals(items[i])) {
            removeItem(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(10);
    list.addItem("1", 0);
    list.addItem("3", 1);
    list.addItem("2", 2);
    list.addItem("2", 3);
    list.addItem("4", 4);
    list.addItem("1", 5);
    list.addItem("2", 6);

    System.out.println(list);
    // {1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2}

    list.removeAll("2");

    System.out.println(list);
    // {1, 3, 4, 1}
}
```